# YouTube API v3 videoCategory v.s. guideCategory

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-channels

The YouTube API v3 can return the videoCategory of a video. For example, if you make the following request:

www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=ZCJgvabihQ8&key=apiKey&part=snippet,recordingDetails

You will find that the video with id ZCJgvabihQ8 belongs to Category 24. But how can I get the guideCategory id instead of the videoCategory id?

Answer (score 2):

from the Doc

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/guideCategories

*A guideCategory resource identifies a category that YouTube algorithmically assigns based on a channel's content or other indicators, such as the channel's popularity. The list is similar to video categories, with the difference being that a video's uploader can assign a video category but only YouTube can assign a channel category.*

The guideCategory is assigned to a channel, not to a video, and I believe that can be used only to list channels

Comment: Actually there is no possibility to list the guideCategory with channels/list. I have no idea how to get the connection guideCategory<->channel

Comment: Check comments under this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19417749/1626392. Might help somebody for future references.