# Youtube API - get video's guideCategory

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api, channel

I'm struggling a bit with retrieving a video's guideCategory using Youtube API V3.

Since channel search filter uses guideCategory instead of videoCategory, I would like to assign videos to their corresponding guideCategory.

The problem is that videos API's response contains only videoCategory but no guideCategory.

Is it possible to receive a video's guideCategory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [document](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/guideCategories):

> A **`guideCategory`** resource identifies **a category that YouTube algorithmically assigns based on a channel's content or other indicators, such as the channel's popularity**. The list is similar to video categories, with the difference being that a video's uploader can assign a video category but **only YouTube can assign a channel category**.

As this related SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14665287/5995040) and the above statement indicated that "guideCategory is assigned to a channel, not to a video, and I believe that can be used only to list channels."